# What should i select Static class or concrete class?

Tags: design-patterns

I need to create a mapper which will map DataTable into an Object of a class(Just set every property into class by DataTable column)

I am thinking below possibilities:

1. Create a Static class and Static method signature like  Map(DataTable obj).
2. Create a Concrete class and Static method signature like  Map(DataTable obj).
3. Create a Concrete class and Non Static metho signature like  Map(DataTable obj).)

What should i do?

Comment: In what programming language ?

Comment: I am using C# in ASP.NET Web API

Comment: [Here's an interesting artlcle](https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/03/static-functions). Apparently the same debate took place within Automapper development.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your particular use case and the standards applied in your organisation/codebase - personally, I would consider the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and create a mapper interface - and then create concrete classes that implement that interface for every mapper that you want.

That way, your code isn't dependent on hard-coded mappers and it becomes easier to test the code that calls the mapping logic, since you can stub/mock the mapper objects.

Comment: Its just first cut of my code so i am unaware of future mappers.. I don't want to create Interface and DI because if In future no any mappers comes then it will go waste ... I will definitely go for DI when any other mappers come in future. Now about my current use case (I have mentioned i just need to map DataTable into Class nothing else) and its my first cut of so no standards are currently being used i will create standards.  Kindly suggest me what should i do?

Comment: Even if there's only a single mapper, I would still create a mapping interface and create an implementation to pass through to the code that calls the mapping.  That's my personal preference, but I don't see it as a waste to create an interface and code to an interface for this.  It can still simplify testing and it's still good practice.  In effect, it's still pretty much option #3 on your original list.